# Event handling between objects of different classes

Tags: c++, oop, event-handling, can-bus

I have a C++ class A that captures frames from CAN interface on a microcontroller. I am trying to implement another class B (and C and D..) that uses the frames captured by class A, one by one. In essence, class A redirects the captured frames to one of the classes from the upper layer depending upon the content of the frame. Should I implement some sort of event handling mechanism (with which I am not so familiar being a programming novice) such that every time a frame is received, an event is fired to the object of the class from upper layer? Or then can I achieve this through inheriting class B, C,... from Class A and so on. Can some one help me how to develop a good and easy logic here?

Edit: A not so great way to do is that I have a switch statement in Class A and then call the so called process method of one of the classes B, C, D,.... based on a case value. However, this is not a smart way because now class A uses classes B, C, D... etc., which I don't want. Class A shouldn't know about classes B, C, D,.....

Comment: I would probably define a common interface (base class) for each of the processors, which would declare a "work/process" function. I would store all of them in a container. I would have a "controller" class that would use class A to get the frame and pass it to each of the list controllers. Now, how you generate the list of controllers is up to you, depending whether order is important etc...

Comment: I made an edit. Can you have a look again?

Comment: I get it, you mean one and only one of classes B, C or D can handle the frame. You know which by one of the field values. This is a very common use of the Factory design pattern, look it up on google. If you don't know which, then you could use the chain of responsibility pattern which is less common, but I could write some pseudocode for that if you want.

Comment: That would be really helpful if you could write a pseudo code.

Comment: Sure, but which version? Can you tell by looking at the frame which class can handle it? Or you can't tell until you try?

Comment: I did google factory design pattern. chain of responsibility doesn't seem a good idea as for each type  of frame that class A captures over the CAN, only one class among B, C, D handles that frame.

Answer (score 0):

for example: class A contains `std::list<B*>`, where B is a base class with some `virtual` handler method. Several classes (C, D, E) inherit class B and overload this method. Then you just add instances of derived classes to list in A by pointer (for example: `std::list<B*> workers {new C, new D, new E};`), and call overloaded method for each instance. Each class decides for itself if it accepts current frame and processes it in own way.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the [Observer design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). Basically, you can have an observable class (in your case `class A`) and multiple observers (in your case `class B` `class C` etc). The observers will register themselves with the observable class for event notification. I have a sample code [EventInterface Model](https://github.com/VishalGandhi1983/EventInterfaceModel.git) that allows Qt style connections between objects. All the application needs to do is connect observable object's event with observer object's event handler.